# Angular Material 2 nested form validation on submit

Tags: angular, validation, input, angular2-forms, angular-material2

I'm trying to use Angular Material with formGroup in Angular 2 and I have a issue with input validation for nested formControls in differents components.

My problem is: when submitting a form, only the input in the first formGroup get notified that the form has been submitted.

I have created the following exemple:

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
      nested: this._fb.group({
           id: ['', Validators.required]
      }),
      id: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
}
```

I have a simple formGroup with one nested formController. This is my HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <md-input-container>
    <input mdInput required formControlName="id">
  </md-input-container>
  <other-component [myFormGroup]="myForm" myFormGroupName="nested"></other-component>
  <button md-raised-button type="submit">Rechercher</button>
</form>
```

The other component just display another input.

I made a plunker to illustrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/WR0cmVOhIfCdkqAVc8xX

You can notice that if I enter a field and quit it right away, the red error line appears on both input. But, if I touch none of the two input and I click on submit, only the non-nested input get underlined. This is because the nested one don't get the information that the form was submitted, even if I pass the formGroup object as a parameter.

Any idea of how can I resolve this problem? How can I make the first input aware of the submitted form?

Thank you a lot !

Comment: In your plunkr, if I click submit and nothing else, I see both inputs underlined in red.

Comment: For me the plunker does not compile, and the code is different from your question...

Comment: Yep sorry I update my plunkr as my exemple was actually working. The new plunkr illustrate my problem, validation on submit isnot working in case of nested components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular doesn't add `mat-input-invalid` class to your nested control. Let's think why?

Here is how class binding for `MdInputContainer` looks like:

```typescript
'[class.mat-input-invalid]': '_mdInputChild._isErrorState',
```

and here is the corresponding style that makes your border red.

```typescript
.mat-input-invalid .mat-input-ripple {
    background-color: #f44336; // red
}
```

if you will investigate how `_isErrorState` property is calculated you can notice that it checks `FormGroupDirective.submitted` property.

```typescript
function defaultErrorStateMatcher(control, form) {
    var /** @type {?} */ isSubmitted = form && form.submitted; <----
    return !!(control.invalid && (control.touched || isSubmitted));
}
```

Since you are creating two `FormGroupDirective` directives only top-level directive will be submitted.

You can work around it by using reactive `FormControlDirective`

**other.component.ts**

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'other-component',
  template: `
      <md-input-container >
        <input mdInput required [formControl]="control">
      </md-input-container>
  `
})
export class OtherComponent  {
  @Input() subname: string;
  @Input() formobj: any;

  control: FormControl;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.control = this.formobj.get([this.subname, 'id'])
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/mpGMoBEZcqqx04K6gKxH?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks Yurzui, It is exactly what I was looking for. The point here is that I need to pass the whole FormGroup object to my nested components instead of passing just the sub FormGroup object. At first I throught passing direcly myForm.get('nested') as a parameter of my other component would do the trick, but no, my nested components needs a reference to the whole formGroup object.